# Incorrect character in browser

Tags: php

I have code like

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

echo 'Hello Loréane !';
```

the e character is not printed properly. How should i fix the code without removing or altering exiting lines of code ?

This is what i get in browser

```
Hello Lor�ane !
```

Comment: Please always show an example of what exactly goes wrong, if possible copy+paste the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your PHP source file is encoded as UTF-8. It is probably encoded als Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1.

Comment: please see my code update and let me know how do i encode my php file in UTF-8

Comment: @pradeep you need to select UTF-8 encoding when saving the file in your editor or IDE.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Why it works after we change the encoding type in file , even though we sent UTF-8 headers before doesn't  work ?

Comment: @vimal because the header only *promises* that the content is going to be UTF-8. it doesn't change the actual data. The data needs to match the encoding set in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your file in encoding utf-8 and add

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

into your head tags.